# Is there a simple way of limiting the number of child processes that execute in parallel?

Tags: bash, shell, rsync, background-process, parallelism

I have a bash script that kicks off multiple rsync processes in parallel. I'd like to limit the number of simultaneous child processes but not serialize the whole script.

Here's a simplified version of the current script:

```
#!/bin/bash
(
  flock -n 200 || exit 0
  {
    for f in $(ssh $1 ls /var/images/)
    do
      rsync … &
    done
    wait
  } &> /var/log/my.log
) 200>/var/lock/my.lockfile
```

I believe `xargs` with `--max-procs` [might be a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6513254/533832) but I can't figure out how to integrate that with my script. Can it be done like this, or is there a better way?

Comment: Why don't you let rsync do its job? You can use its recursive option...

Comment: @Spack because it's not parallel? I don't need the recursive option, the 30-odd files I'm rsync-ing are all in the same directory, and they range in size from 10GB to 800Gb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
ssh "$1" "find /var/images -type f -print0" |
  xargs --null --replace --max-procs=X rsync "${1}:{}" /my/destination
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: thanks, what does `"host:{}"` mean btw?

Comment: using xargs, the replace option will replace any `{}` by the actual argument, here the path to your file. Since you are using rsync, you should provide the host to connect to. In your script, you can replace `host` by `$1`.

Comment: `man xargs` says: "Use the -n option with -P; otherwise chances are that only one exec will be done". Should I be using -n1 here?

Comment: @JackDouglas if you use the replace option,`-i` , the `-n` is useless.